# Grand total (sencha: ExtJS)?

Tags: extjs

I have implemented a pivot grid using extjs, but I would like to get rid of Grand total field.So,How do I remove grand total form pivot grid(sencha ExtJS)?

Comment: Can you add a sencha fiddle with what you have?

Comment: Here it is: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2lml

Answer (score 0):

Try to configure like this:

```
{
    xtype: 'pivotgrid',

    matrix: {

        rowSubTotalsPosition:       'none',

        rowGrandTotalsPosition:     'none',

        colSubTotalsPosition:       'none',

        colGrandTotalsPosition:     'none'

    
    }
}
```